# google maps supported mobile devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-markers

I am building a mobile site that is based on google maps, basically displays a standard google map and some markers on it. What i would like to do and haven't found and info on it, is to detect mobile devices that don't support google maps and subsequently custom markers on it, using javascript maybe?

I would really appreciate if anyone could provide an example or point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance
EV

Answer (score 0):

List of supported mobile browsers:

http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=39891

I had a look and I think there probably isn't an API solution that allows you to check (like `GoogleMaps.supportsThisBrowser()`. So I think you might just have to sniff which browser version the user is using:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

And then compare their browser against the above list.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en-EN#browsersupport) is a bit unspecific and only states:

- IE 7.0+, without Compatibility mode (Windows)
- Firefox 3.0+ (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)
- Safari 4+ (Mac OS X, iOS)
- Chrome (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux)
- Android
- BlackBerry 6
- Dolfin 2.0+ (Samsung Bada)

But I read somwhere else that Android prior version 2.1 and iOS prior 4.0 is not supported either. It also depends on the specific device (HTC Hero for example is very slow rendering complex maps in the browser).